# vuex store management overwrites the table in ionic

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuex

**Code:** https://github.com/cbsmerveguel/ionicblank

Hi all,

I am very new at vuejs and vuejs with ionic. I wanted to give it a try with a master-detail view, in which at master page a table will be located, and in the detail view the details of the selected item from that table. I am following this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQ4zmFy4d7Y&t=7439s) video in parallel to do it. The vuex store management worked well, and now I am able to get the details of the selected item, however it came with 2 separate issues:

1. Right after going in to the detail view and navigating back -> overwrites the table data. As I run the app for the first time, everything is fine. However as I navigate into the second item and navigate back, the first item's inspectionId would be overwritten with the navigated item. Same for any item I am selecting, it keeps overwriting the first item's inspectionId.

[image]

**After navigating into the 2. item and navigating back to home**

[image]

2. Although I am able to get the details of the selected item into the object page, it only displays the inspectionId. Not the Material or Status, these values keep getting picked up from the very first item.
   [image]

Any comment, help would be very much so appreciated.

**Code has been shared in the repo:** https://github.com/cbsmerveguel/ionicblank

Comment: A good question should include the minimal code necessary to understand the issue, not with links to the full repo.  See [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The description of the issue is good, but code should always be included related to anything you're describing (i.e. code relevant to the issue).  Luckily, your app is not so large that I was able to find the issue with a quick look, but in the future please provide code along with your descriptions :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @yoduh. I am aware of that, however since the issue could due to be anything, I thought repo might make more sense in this case. No worries, I will be more careful next time.

Comment: @yoduh this is correct, which is why we vote to close questions without code, instead of answering them. Doubly so for a question that is caused by a typo.

Comment: sure, I agree, except in this case the level of effort to answer the question, even without specific code, was low enough (personally speaking) that I opted to help OP rather than vote to close, but now that OP has been helped I'm happy to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/cbsmerveguel/ionicblank/blob/master/src/store/index.ts#L32) is the line of code causing the error.

`data.id = inspectionId` is an assignment, so whatever you click becomes assigned to the first object of your `tableData` array. What you mean to do is a comparison:

```js
data.id === inspectionId
```